# fullPage.js navigation not working after jquery load content

Tags: jquery, ajax, navigation, load, fullpage.js

I have a fullPage slider that is loaded on the page when clicking on a link.

This is the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>

<section id="introduction">
    <a class="half-intro page-link" href="intuitive-office.html"></a>
    <a class="half-intro page-link" href="intuitive-estate.html"></a>
</section>

<main id="main-container"></main>

<script src="js/j.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When clicking on intuitive-office.html, the content from that page is loaded inside `<main id="main-container"></main>`.

That works fine, fullPage.js also works but only on mouse scroll. The navigation dots don't work at all.
They do work when I click on them from intuitive-office.html but they don't when the fullPage slider is pulled in with jquery load.

This is the content from intuitive-office.html page

```
<main>
    <div id="scroll-container">
        <section class="section">
            <div class="centered">
                <h2>This is some text</h2>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="section">
            <div class="centered">
                <h2>This is some text 2</h2>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="section">
            <div class="centered">
                <h2>This is some text 3</h2>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</main>
```

And this is the script I'm using

```
(function($){

    var pageScroll = function(){
        $('#scroll-container').fullpage({
            navigation: true,
            navigationPosition: 'right'
        });
    };
    pageScroll();

    // load content
    String.prototype.decodeHTML = function() {
        return $("<div>", {html: "" + this}).html();
    };

    var $main = $("main"),

    init = function() {
        pageScroll();
    },

    ajaxLoad = function(html) {
        document.title = html
        .match(/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/)[1]
        .trim()
        .decodeHTML();

        init();
    },

    loadPage = function(href) {
        $main.load(href + " main>*", ajaxLoad);
    };

    //init();

    $(window).on("popstate", function(e) {
        if (e.originalEvent.state !== null) {
            loadPage(location.href);
        }
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".page-link", function() {
        var href = $(this).attr("href");

        if (href.indexOf(document.domain) > -1 || href.indexOf(':') === -1) {
            history.pushState({}, '', href);
            loadPage(href);
            return false;
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: A reproduction in jsfiddle or codepen would be ideal to help you.

Comment: Hi Alvaro, thank you for your reply. Your plugin is just amazing! I created a fiddle and it worked fine..! It wasn't a fullpage.js bug, it was my mistake in the js. Thanks again